# Bar Graphic in JupyterHub

Tags: python, graphics, jupyterhub

How to create a bar graphic in python jupyterhub with categories and subcategories grouped by genre like this graphic that I made in Excel. I find a code but that did not help me.

The method for making a graphic with a sub-category

[image: image of the graph]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.